# Magento 2 Insert data in custom column of order table

Tags: magento2, database, sales-order

I have added a custom column in Magento 2 **"sales_order"** table from my custom module, Now I want to insert value in this column.Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: for this you have to make a plugin and use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession in __construct{$this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a observer event **sales_order_place_after**.

**Creates `etc/events.xml` file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
       <observer name="order info" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\Orderinfo" />
   </event>


</config>
```

**Create a observer class**

```
class Orderinfo implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order= $observer->getData('order');
     $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        "write your logic here for set data in sales_order"
    }
}
```

Comment: But it will call "execute" method when  event is triggered, I want to insert column value at shipping method selection.

Comment: I want to save data in custom column in sales order grid table not sale order table

Comment: @Sourav are you able to save values in custom column in sales_order_grid ?